# Triangle and Quadrilateral Areas.

Tags: triangles, quadrilateral

In triangle ABC, E is a point on AC and F is a point on AB. BE and CF intersect
at D. If the areas of triangles BDF, BCD and CDE are 3, 7 and 7 respectively,
what is the area of the quadrilateral AEDF?

[image: Triangle ABC]

I tried to solve the question as the ratios of the areas of pentagon EDFBC and the area of the quadrilateral AEDF.  Area of pentagon = 17.   I couldn't proceed from here.   Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the notation $[UVW]$ to denote the area of triangle $UVW$.

Key principle:

- If two triangles have equal altitudes, the ratio of their areas is equal to the ratio of the corresponding bases for those altitudes.

Draw line segment $AD$.

Let $x=[ADF]$, and let $y=[ADE]$.

Applying the key principle, we get
$$\frac{x+3}{y}=[ADB]:[ADE]=BD:DE= [BCD]:[CDE] = 7:7 = 1:1$$
and also
$$\frac{x}{y+7}=[ADF]:[ADC]=FD:DC= [BDF]:[BCD] = 3:7
\qquad\;\;\;\;\;$$
Solving the system
$$
\begin{cases}
{\Large{\frac{x+3}{y}}}=1\\[4pt]
{\Large{\frac{x}{y+7}}}={\large{\frac{3}{7}}}\\
\end{cases}
$$
for $x,y$ yields
$$x=\frac{15}{2},\;\;\;y=\frac{21}{2}$$
so the area of quadrilateral $AEDF$ is $x+y=18$.